# Screen closes and exits during node.js server long process

Tags: linux, apache, shell, terminal, gnu-screen

I don't have Sudo access, so currently i can't install 'Forever' https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Instead i am simply using 'Screen'.

I am running a node.js server, at a random point, the node server stops, and screen exits. I cannot seem to collect any error data on this. I seem to be completely unaware of why its happening and cannot think of a way to catch what is happening. It doesn't happen often (maybe 1 time per day). When i load putty back up and login to my Apache server through terminal, i type screen -x or screen -r and it tells me there are no screens attached. The node server process definitely stops because the app it runs stops working.

Obviously i can't post all the code here, there is tons of it. But everything appears to work wonderfully, except every now and then, something goes wrong and it closes the attached screen.

If there was a problem with the node server, i would expect a crash, and the attached screen would stay attached. There would be an error outputted to the terminal for me to see when i open it. But in this case, it totally closes the attached screen.

Does anybody know what kind of error can cause this?

On a side note, is there an alternative to 'Forever' that can be installed without Sudo access?

Answer (score 0):

My node version wasn't correct which is why Forever wasn't installing. I didn't need SUDO after all. I am now using Forever and hopefully this will shed light on what is going on as i have a out.log file which should catch whatever the problem is. :-)